# Using “razor” outside of ASPNET Core 2.0

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Has anyone ever managed to run RAZOR out of aspnet core 2.0? I would like to use it in place of T4 templates that are very dependent on Visual Studio.

I already managed to get the C # intermediate code, but I still could not convert it to string again.

1) Am I on the right path?

2) How do I execute the C # code that was generated (and is in string form)? If possible, I would like it to be the same way as ASPNET CORE does.

**C# (Generator code is extensive for stackoverflow)**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/T6Slzp

**Views\MyView.cshtml**

```csharp
@{
    string[] members = {"Jani", "Hege", "Kai", "Jim"};
    int i = Array.IndexOf(members, "Kai")+1;
    int len = members.Length;
    string x = members[2-1];
}

<html>
<body>
    <h3>The time is @DateTime.UtcNow</h3>
    @foreach (var person in members)
    {
        <p>@person</p>
    }

    <p>The number of names in Members are @len</p>
    <p>The person at position 2 is @x</p>
    <p>Kai is now in position @i</p>

    @{
        var j = 0;
        while (j < 5)
        {
            j += 1;
            <p>Line @j</p>
        }
    }
</body>
</html>
```

**Output string (C# code)**

```csharp
// <auto-generated/>
#pragma warning disable 1591
namespace RuntimeNamespace
{
    #line hidden
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    internal class TestView : BaseView
    {
        #pragma warning disable 1998
        public async override global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
#line 1 "TestView.cshtml"

    string[] members = {"Jani", "Hege", "Kai", "Jim"};
    int i = Array.IndexOf(members, "Kai")+1;
    int len = members.Length;
    string x = members[2-1];

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("\n<html>\n<body>\n    <h3>The time is ");
#line 10 "TestView.cshtml"
               Write(DateTime.UtcNow);

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("</h3>\n");
#line 11 "TestView.cshtml"
     foreach (var person in members)
    {

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("        <p>");
#line 13 "TestView.cshtml"
      Write(person);

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("</p>\n");
#line 14 "TestView.cshtml"
    }

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("\n    <p>The number of names in Members are ");
#line 16 "TestView.cshtml"
                                     Write(len);

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("</p>\n    <p>The person at position 2 is ");
#line 17 "TestView.cshtml"
                              Write(x);

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("</p>\n    <p>Kai is now in position ");
#line 18 "TestView.cshtml"
                         Write(i);

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("</p>\n\n");
#line 20 "TestView.cshtml"

        var j = 0;
        while (j < 5)
        {
            j += 1;

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("            <p>Line ");
#line 25 "TestView.cshtml"
               Write(j);

#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("</p>\n");
#line 26 "TestView.cshtml"
        }


#line default
#line hidden
            WriteLiteral("</body>\n</html>\n\n\n\n");
        }
        #pragma warning restore 1998
    }
}
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty close I'd say. You might also want to check out the [Asp Net Core Scaffolding project on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/tree/dev/src/VS.Web.CG.Templating) as that uses Razor in a very similar way under the hood (this is the scaffolding tool used natively within Visual Studio for ASP .net Core projects).

My `BaseView` is slightly different to yours but it looks like you should just need to do the following:

```cs
Type compiledType = Compile(cSharpDocument.GeneratedCode);
BaseView razorTemplate = (BaseView)Activator.CreateInstance(compiledType);
var result = await razorTemplate.ExecuteAsync();
string output = razorTemplate.ToString();
```

Where `Compile` and `GetAssembly` are implemented as follows:

```cs
private Type Compile(string content)
{
    SyntaxTree[] syntaxTrees = new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(content) };

    string dummyAssemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();

    CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(dummyAssemblyName,
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
            syntaxTrees: syntaxTrees,
            references: _references);

    Assembly result = GetAssembly(compilation);

    Type type = result.GetExportedTypes().First();

    return type;
}

private static Assembly GetAssembly(Compilation compilation)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

        if (!result.Success)
        {
            DiagnosticFormatter formatter = new DiagnosticFormatter();

            IEnumerable<string> errorMessages = result.Diagnostics
                                    .Where(d => d.IsWarningAsError || d.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error)
                                    .Select(d => formatter.Format(d));

            throw new Exception($"Errors encountered whilst compiling assembly: {String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorMessages)}");
        }

        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Assembly assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(ms);

        return assembly;
    }
}
```